# Свойства исключающего или

Tags: алгоритм, xor

Есть некоторый набор целых положительных чисел (0 может входить) и число M

```
A1,A2,...,An
```

Удовлетворяющий следующим свойствам:

```
A1+A2+...+An = M
A1^A2^...^An = 0
```

И нужно найти количество наборов таких чисел длины N. Не знаю даже, как подступиться к задаче. Пытался что-то выводить из свойств исключающего или, но ни до чего толкового не дошел

Comment: Мне кажется я уже видел эту задачу на этом ресурсе…

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ничего похожего найти не получается :(

Comment: Что-то ничего умнее перебора пока не могу придумать

Comment: @AlexeyTen, если бы не ограничение по времени, написал бы хотя бы перебор, а так вообще нет идей, что делать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Найдём максимальную степень двойки `K`, такую, что `2^K <= M` (т.е. номер старшего единичного бита в `M`). Тогда в сумме `M` могут участвовать два бита (нам же нужны парные) с номером `K-1`, распределённые по `N` местам. Таких распределений (сочетаний) `C(N, 2)`. Запомним это число `P`. Если убрать эти два бита, то останется значение `M-2^K`, продолжим решать для него задачу рекурсивно до младших битов, получим число `P'`. А объединением их будет произведение количества вариантов `Q = P * P'`

Однако вместо пары старших битов в сумме может участвовать четвёрка, пара, или ноль битов с номером `K-2` и так далее. Поэтому для сборки реального результата нужно учесть все эти варианты.

```
F(M,K) = [C(N,2)*F(M-2^K,K-1)]+[C[N,4]*F(M-2^K,K-2)]+[C[N,2]*F(M-2^(K-1),K-2)]+[C(N,8)*F(M-2^K,K-3)]+...
            |                     |                       |
         есть два старших бита    |                       |                          
                                  |                       |
                    старших нет, есть четыре вторых       |
                                                старших нет, есть два вторых      
                                                                            нет старших и вторых, есть восемь третьих
```

Для вычисления результата можно создать таблицу размером `MxK` и заполнять её ряд за рядом.